# Why is the # character seen as a 'word' character in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Why is the # character seen as a 'word' character in Perl?  Or am I misunderstanding how this code is supposed to work?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filename = "Something_with_#_sign.jpg";

$filename =~ s/        # substitute...
                [^             # characters which are NOT:
                \w                # "word" characters
                ]              # end of character classes
                /_/xg;     # ...with an underscore

print "$filename\n";
```

Yields:

```
Something_with_#_sign.jpg
```

I would have expected the # sign to have been replaced by an _ (underscore).

Comment: Verbose regex rules do not affect character classes. `[^\w]` must be written on 1 line solidly.

Comment: You can add `use re 'debug';` to look at what the regex engine is doing. That might also shed some light.

Comment: Remove your comments, and put it on a single line.  It works that way.

Comment: The direct answer to the question in your title, "Why is the # character seen as a 'word' character in Perl?" is "It isn't".

Comment: Thanks everyone, apparently I was too in love with commenting my regex and using that cool "ignore whitespace" trick.  Not so cool anymore.

Comment: You can replace `[^\w]` with `\W`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/x` doesn't modify the syntax of character classes (or of `\x20`, or of `s{3,4}`, etc, etc), so

```
[^             # characters which are NOT:
\w                # "word" characters
]              # end of character classes
```

is a weird way of writing

```
[^ "#:NOTacdefhilnorst\n\w]
```

Comment: Actually, the regex can be read as `[^             # characters which are NOT:\n
\w                # "word" characters\n]`. And verbose modifier does not modify any syntax, it modifies the *meaning* of literal whitespace outside of character classes.

Comment: @stribizhev, It does change syntax. Without `/x`, the syntax of a repetition is `ATOM '*'` With `/x`, the syntax of a repetition is `WHITESPACE* ATOM WHITESPACE* '*'`

Comment: Yes, and the reason the pattern is parsed differently is because the syntax changed.